# create java jar in lambda function using python

Tags: python

I am trying to create java jar with the files in AWS S3 by **Lambda function** using **Python**

I have tried in both ways

```
import os
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    os.system('jar cf abc.jar, file1.txt, file2.txt')
    return "Success"
```

and

```
import subprocess
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    subprocess.call('jar cf abc.jar, file1.txt, file2.txt')
    return "Success"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `commas`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('jar cf abc.jar *.py')
# import os
# os.system('jar cf abc.jar *.py')
print("Done")
```

Output :

```
Done

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Verifying :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('jar tvf abc.jar')
# import os
# os.system('jar tvf abc.jar')
```

Output :

```
     0 Wed Feb 28 18:22:32 IST 2018 META-INF/
    68 Wed Feb 28 18:22:32 IST 2018 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   196 Wed Jan 24 20:27:32 IST 2018 dirTut.py
   438 Tue Jan 09 20:44:00 IST 2018 epochtodatetime.py
  1540 Sun Jan 07 15:30:42 IST 2018 firstServer.py
   164 Sun Jan 14 19:34:20 IST 2018 flaskTut.py
   295 Tue Jan 09 17:59:20 IST 2018 funcOverriding.py
   390 Tue Jan 09 16:55:24 IST 2018 underscore.py
```

Comment: I am running in AWS Lambda function.

Comment: Yes I need to run this in AWS Lambda and create jar